# Unable to activate Fulfilment Designer from XOM Administration

Tags: vlocity

I am trying to activate the Fulfilment Designer from the Vlocity XOM Administration. Although I have enabled the profile for the Fulfilment Designer app, enabled LWS and given the visibilty for the app, I receive this exception when I click on Activate

[image: Exception received]

Anyone with the same issue?

Thanks,
Federico